# Explicit formula for $\int \text{sinc}(2 \pi x)^{2 k-1} \, \mathrm dx$?

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

This is very similar to other questions people have asked (I've Googled extensively), but not identical. I have been trying to use integration by parts to generate an explicit formula in terms of $x$ for the indefinite integral

$$\int \text{sinc}^{2 k-1}(2 \pi  x) \, \mathrm dx$$

There's a lot of guidance on finding definite integrals for lower powers of $\text{sinc}$, and I found a general expression for the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ for any positive integer power $k$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894649/closed-form-for-integral-of-integer-powers-of-sinc-function?rq=1)... But none of these are quite what I'm looking for, and it turns out they don't help me.

I have tried splitting $\text{sinc}^{2 k-1}(2 \pi  x)$ into parts many different ways. Aside from the obvious numerator-denominator split, I've tried using the complex exponential for $\sin$, I've tried converting $\sin^2$ to an expression in $\cos$... But after each iteration of integration by parts, I end up with a new integral that seems more complex than the first. I've tunneled down $4$ iterations in each case, and the functions just get more and more unwieldy.

There has to be a way because some web pages reference old books with a solution in them. But I don't have access to a library.

Could someone please talk me through how to handle this? (Or at least provide a solution!)

Comment: For any $k$, a CAS provide an explicit solution but really messy. For example, for $k=3$, $6144 \pi ^5 x^4\,I_3$ is $$80 \pi ^4 x^4 \text{Si}(2 \pi  x)-3240 \pi ^4 x^4 \text{Si}(6 \pi  x)+5000 \pi ^4
   x^4 \text{Si}(10 \pi  x)+40 \pi ^3 x^3 \cos (2 \pi  x)-540 \pi ^3 x^3 \cos (6
   \pi  x)+500 \pi ^3 x^3 \cos (10 \pi  x)+20 \pi ^2 x^2 \sin (2 \pi  x)-90 \pi ^2
   x^2 \sin (6 \pi  x)+50 \pi ^2 x^2 \sin (10 \pi  x)-30 \sin (2 \pi  x)+15 \sin (6
   \pi  x)-3 \sin (10 \pi  x)-20 \pi  x \cos (2 \pi  x)+30 \pi  x \cos (6 \pi 
   x)-10 \pi  x \cos (10 \pi  x)$$

Comment: Thanks @Claude. But I was kind of hoping that there might be a closed form solution, perhaps like the solution for the definite integral found [here][1]...


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930438/find-integral-of-operatornamesinc-pi-x-over-range-x-0-1

Comment: As I wrote, the problem is to get a general formula for $I_k$. I guess that for any specific value of $k$, we can get an explicit result.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies (and thanks) to all who have read or responded. It seems my Googling was nowhere nears thorough as I had thought! I always take Wikipedia with a pinch of salt, but I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) that these integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

But I'd be thrilled if someone could prove Wikipedia wrong!